# AWS Cognito 90 day automated Password rotation

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, amazon-cognito

I have a requirement to create an automated password reset script. I created a custom field in order to try and track this and also hope I can access some of the standard fields. This script should find users with the following criteria:

The latest of any of the following 3 dates that are >= 90 days ago : Sign_Up, Forgot_Password, or custom:pwdCreateDate

I can't seem to find any boto3 cognito client ways of getting the information on this except for forgot password which shows up in admin_list_user_auth_events and that response doesn't include username in the response.  I suppose since you provide username to get the events you can figure out a way to find the latest forgot password from the events and tie it to the username.

Has anyone else implemented any boto3 automation to set the account to force password reset based on any of these fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is where i landed, take it with the understanding that coginito has some limitations which make true flawless password rotation difficult. Also know if you can make the script more efficient you should because in lambda you probably time out with more than about 350 users due to the 5RPS on the admin API.

Prerequisites : set the lambda function to 5 concurrency or you will exceed the limit of 5RPS.  1 mutable field in your cognito userpool attributes to put a date in.  a custom lambda zip file that includes pandas saved to s3.

```
import os
import sys

# this adds the parent directory of bin so we can find the  module
parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir))
sys.path.append(parent_dir)
#This addes venv lib/python2.7/site-packages/ to the search path
mod_path = os.path.abspath(parent_dir+"/lib/python"+str(sys.version_info[0])+"."+str(sys.version_info[1])+"/site-packages/")
sys.path.append(mod_path)

import boto3
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import time

current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
# Use this one for the parent directory
ENV_ROOT =  os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current_path, os.path.pardir))
# Use this one for the current directory
#ENV_ROOT =  os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current_path))
sys.path.append(ENV_ROOT)

#if __name__ == "__main__":
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    user_pool_id = os.environ['USER_POOL_ID']
    idp_client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
    users_list = []
    page_token = None    
    dateToday = datetime.datetime.today().date()

    def update_user(user) :
        idp_client.admin_update_user_attributes(
            UserPoolId = user_pool_id,
            Username = user,
            UserStatus = 'RESET_REQUIRED',
            UserAttributes = [
                    {
                        'Name': 'custom:pwdCreateDate',
                        'Value': str(dateToday)
                    }            
                ]
            )   


    users = idp_client.list_users(
        UserPoolId = user_pool_id
        )
    for user in users['Users']: users_list.append(user['Username'])
    page_token = users['PaginationToken']

    while 'PaginationToken' in users :
        users = idp_client.list_users(
            UserPoolId = user_pool_id,
            PaginationToken = page_token
            )
        for user in users["Users"]: users_list.append(user["Username"])

        if 'PaginationToken' in users :
            page_token = users['PaginationToken']

    attrPwdDates = []
    for i in range(len(users_list)) :
        userAttributes = idp_client.admin_get_user(
                UserPoolId = user_pool_id,
                Username = users_list[i]
                )
        for a in userAttributes['UserAttributes'] :
            if a['Name'] == 'custom:pwdCreateDate' :
                attrPwdDates.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(a['Value'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').date())
        time.sleep(1.0)

    list_of_userattr_tuples = list(zip(users_list, attrPwdDates))                            
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(list_of_userattr_tuples,columns = ['Username','Password_Last_Set'])

    authPwdDates = []
    for i in range(len(users_list)) :
        authEvents = idp_client.admin_list_user_auth_events(
        UserPoolId = user_pool_id,
        Username = users_list[i]
        )

        for event in authEvents['AuthEvents'] :
            if event['EventType'] == 'ForgotPassword' and event['EventResponse'] == 'Pass' :
                authPwdDates.append(event['CreationDate'].date())
                break
        time.sleep(1.0)

    list_of_userauth_tuples = list(zip(users_list, authPwdDates))        
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(list_of_userauth_tuples,columns = ['Username','Password_Last_Forgot'])

    df3 = df1.merge(df2,how='left', on = 'Username')

    df3[['Password_Last_Set','Password_Last_Forgot']] = df3[['Password_Last_Set','Password_Last_Forgot']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

    cols = ['Password_Last_Set','Password_Last_Forgot']
    df4 = df3.loc[df3[cols].max(axis=1)<=pd.Timestamp.now() - pd.Timedelta(90, unit='d'), 'Username']

    for i,r in df4.iterrows() :
        update_user(r['Username'])
```